# Control user access from central place

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a database with a Users and Roles table with a 3 layer project (DAL to store the database entities etc, BAL to store the business logic such as CRUD operations and the site itself).

Roles are

1. Administrator - Full access
2. HR - Create and view employees (Users)
3. GeneralUser - can view employees but not create

Users table has a RoleID column storing the value of the role as above (1,2 etc)

I enabled Forms Auth by adding

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="site" loginUrl="/login/" protection="All" timeout="120" slidingExpiration="false" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

I have some pages which access/functions are based on the users role so GeneralUser cant create an employee.

How could i restrict their access from a central place without having to go into all pages individually and write something like

```
if (user.role != HR)
{
  CreateButton.Visible = false;
}
```